# How to Publish articles after some time interval like wordpress in php mysql

Tags: php

I want to publish articles after sometime like it's possible in wordpress from my application. Can anybody give me a rought idea sql/php about it ? Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  Could you clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a PublishOn field to your Post/Page table. So whevener you are displaying the list of pages or posts, you will check if the current date is greater than the publish date or not. If the current date is greater than the publish date, the post is "published" else its not. So something like

```
Select * from posts where PublishOn < getdate();
```

THat will result in all the "Published" posts.

Comment: getdate() is in MSSSQL, but check the date function for mysql before you use it